# Sequences(monotonic or not)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've been struggling to see whether this sequence $\bigg(\frac{-3n}{n^2-1}\bigg)$ is decreasing or increasing or neither. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try calculating the first several terms?

Comment: You can take a look at $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ and compare the numerator and the denominator. For suitable $n$ of course...

Comment: Note that your OP was requested for closure because you didn't show your work and effort on that. Keep in mind that for the next time and refer to [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Consider that

$$f(x)=\frac{-3x}{x^2-1} \implies f'(x)=\frac{3(x^2+1)}{(x^2-1)^2}.$$

Comment: so this is increasing? Does it not matter that since lim of n ->1 will result in a -infinity or infinity?

Comment: @Mr_nice_guy The sequence is not defined for $n=1$ thus we can assume $n\ge 2$.

Comment: What if it was x^2 -9 as the denominator? would we assume n>=4?

Comment: @Mr_nice_guy Usually when we deal with sequences we are interested to the behaviour for $n$ "large" therefore we can disregard the "initial" values for which the sequence is not well defined.

Comment: I know it says I shouldn't say thanks....but thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mr_nice_guy Otherwise $a_n=\sqrt{2018^{2018}-n}$ is not a sequence since it is not defined for $n>2018^{2018}$.

Comment: so a sequence is only a sequence if it the lim->infinity exists?

Comment: @Mr_nice_guy No what we require is that exists $\bar n$ such that $\forall n\ge \bar n$ we can assign one (and only one) real value to $a_n$. We don't need that the limit exists, think for example to $a_n= \sin n$.

Comment: makes sense...Thanks alot

Comment: @Mr_nice_guy You are welcome. Since you are new here recall that you can accept an answer among the given if you consider the OP was properly answered. You may find more details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Bye

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is increasing. Notice that it is not defined at $n = 1$, so it is defined for $n \geq 2$. Both the numerator and the denominator behave monotonically for all $n \geq 2$, and so it does the ratio. Knowing that $a_2 < 0$ and that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$, this implies that the sequence is monotonically increasing for all $n \geq 2$.

Comment: Carlos, I think you should include the fact that the points $\{(n, a_n)\}$ lie on a hyperbola.  (i.e. "Knowing that $a_2<0$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n=0$, and the fact that the points $\{(n,a_n)\}$ lie on one branch of a hyperbola implies that....").

Comment: Ok i got it...Thanks alot for your help!